# Evaluation of nested integer intervals in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, comparison, intervals

This question is about interval comparison of nested integer intervals.

Assume three ranges of integers, which I call *target ranges* for sake of simplicity. These target ranges never overlap, but may be of different length.

```
> target1 = range(1,10000)
> target2 = range(10001,20000)
> target3 = range(20001,25000)
```

Further assume another range, which I call *test range*, that always has a smaller length than any of the target ranges, but which may cross into an adjacent target range.

```
> test1 = range(900,5000)  # entirely in target1
> test2 = range(9900,10500)  # mostly in target2, but crosses into target1
```

Is there a Python function that helps identify which *target ranges* a *test range* falls into? In case the test range crosses into an adjacent target range, only that target range shall be given that hosts the largest proportion of the test range.

```
> sought_function(test1, [target1, target2, target3])
# 1
> sought_function(test2, [target1, target2, target3])
# 2
```

**EDIT 1**:

In absence of a standard Python function for interval comparison of nested integer intervals, what code would you use? Below is some quick and clunky Python code for a function entitled *nested_in_which* that can certainly be improved.

```
def nested_in_which(test, targets):
    for n, t in enumerate(targets):
        if test[0] in t and test[-1] in t:
            return(n)
        else:
            if test[0] in t and n < len(targets) and test[-1] in targets[n+1]:
                return(n+1) # Overlap comparison not yet implemented
```

Comment: No, no such built-in or standard library function exists.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Fair enough. Can you recommend some library functions that do compare integers ranges which would help me save time as I write the necessary Python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of each range as a set. You want the target range that gives you the largest intersection with the test set.

So if you calculate the length of the intersection between each target and the test and return the index of the max intersection you should have what you want.

Here is some rough code that does it:

```
def which_range( testRange, *targetRanges ):
    testRange = set( testRange )
    tests = [ ( i, len( set( targetRange ).intersection( testRange ) ) ) for i, targetRange in enumerate( targetRanges ) ]
    return max( tests, key=lambda x: x[1] )[0]



>>> which_range( range(9900,10500), range(1,10000), range(10001,20000), range(20001,25000) )
1 # the second target range
>>> which_range( range(900,5000), range(1,10000), range(10001,20000), range(20001,25000) )
0 # the first target range
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion! However, your code forces the user to enter each test range explicitly and not simply pass a list of ranges. Could you adapt it?

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl It doesn't force that. They can call it like so: `which_range( testRange, *someIterableOfRanges )` You should look up the docs on the syntax https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl if you don't want the function signature to be like that, just remove the `*` before `targetRanges` and it will allow you to pass in an iterable without unpacking it.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure want you are trying to do, but if you want to check if a test range included in a target range, you can do:

```
test1[0] in target1 and test1[-1] in target1
=> True
```

Comment: I updated my question to illustrate my aim. Seems like a function that conducts a typical operation; thus, I expected there was such a function.